# Jquery append wont work with dynamic content?

Tags: jquery, html

HI I am making a web application and have buttons that set a variable. I want the variable to be added to the div or element i have creating using a line split. I have tried but with now success I have tried changing the div from a 'P' to a D but it does not work. I have also tried a double click as to not interfere with the single click.

I have run out of ideas.
I originally had this appending at caret but I don't want people to run code inside my textarea.

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fergusp/U4phR/2/)

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var toAdd = "</br>"
    $('input[id="freeSchoolMeals"]').click(function () {
        toAdd = '<div id="fsm">FSM</div>';
        alert(toAdd);
        return false;
    });
    $('input[id="englishAdditional"]').click(function () {
        toAdd = '<div id="eal">EAL</div>';
        alert(toAdd);
        return false;
    });
    $('input[id="giftedTalented"]').click(function () {
        toAdd = '<div id="gt">G&T</div>';
        alert(toAdd);
        return false;
    });
    $('input[id="schoolAction"]').click(function () {
        toAdd = '<div id="sca">ScA</div>';
        alert(toAdd);
        return false;
    });
    $('input[id="schoolActionPlus"]').click(function () {
        toAdd = '<div id="sap">SAP</div>';
        alert(toAdd);
        return false;
    });
    $('input[id="statement"]').click(function () {
        toAdd = '<div id="stm">STM</div>';
        alert(toAdd);
        return false;
    });
    $('input[id="speechLang"]').click(function () {
        toAdd = '<div id="slcn">SLCN</div>';
        alert(toAdd);
        return false;
    });
    $('input[id="specificLearn"]').click(function () {
        toAdd = '<div id="spl">SpLD</div>';
        alert(toAdd);
        return false;
    });
    $('input[id="mildLearn"]').click(function () {
        toAdd = '<div id="mld">MLD</div>';
        alert(toAdd);
        return false;
    });
    $('input[id="behaviour"]').click(function () {
        toAdd = '<div id="besd">BESD</div>';
        alert(toAdd);
        return false;
    });
    $('input[id="autisticSpectrum"]').click(function () {
        toAdd = '<div id="asd">ASD</div>';
        alert(toAdd);
        return false;
    });


    $("p").dblclick(function () {
        var newContent = toAdd;
        $(this).append(newContent);
    });

    $("textarea").keyup(splitLine);

    function splitLine() {
        //$("#opt").empty();
        var lines = $("textarea").val().split(/\n/g);
        for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
            var ele;
            if ($("p:eq(" + i + ")").get(0)) {
                ele = $("p:eq(" + i + ")");
                ele.html(lines[i]);
            } else {
                ele = $("<p>");
                ele.html(lines[i]);
                $("#opt").append($(ele).draggable());
            }
        }
    }
    $("#toggleButton").toggle(function () {
        $('#comments').animate({
            height: 650
        }, 200);
    }, function () {
        $('#comments').animate({
            height: 22
        }, 200);
    });

    $(document).keyup(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) { // enter
            Search();
            return false; //you can also say e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Not really helping with the question, but you really need to DRY that code up.

Comment: @Ferg Agree with Rory, please present a simplfied and succint representation of your problem.

Comment: Also `input[id="freeSchoolMeals"]` could be written as `input#freeSchoolMeals` or `#freeSchoolMeals`

Comment: Id's have to be unique, so please just do `$('#freeSchoolMeals')` and comparable for selection. It's also faster.

Comment: I think you need to have another go at stating what you want to achieve, I think the see 'a' problem but not sure it is 'the' problem

Comment: Hi Guys what do mean by DRY it up? I have only been doing this for a couple of days

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("p").dblclick(function(){
```

will only append the handler to `p`aragraphs that exist at the moment you are attaching the handlers. Since you're adding more `p`aragraphs later, unless you want to attach event handlers dynamically as you create new elements, you need to delegate the event handling to some other element, one that exists when you attach the handlers, such as the `document`. [`$().on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) can perform delegation:

```
$(document).on("dblclick", "p", function(){
```

If you are using an old version of jQuery, use [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) instead:

```
$(document).delegate("p", "dblclick", function(){
```

(you don't need to change anything else than this single line)

Comment: you genius! that worked. so the document.on is basically like another document ready just for the dbl click?

Comment: @Ferg `on` works with any delegate element, any target selector and any event. `$("#delegate").on("event", ".target", handler)`. It's just that `document` is always a viable delegate for anything (it's the ancestor of all elements and it always exists from the very beginning).

Answer (score 1):

The binding `$("p").dblclick()` just bind to all **existing** `p` element when this line is executed. Therefore, all newly created `p` elements from your `spitline` function will not be binded with any event. You need to bind the `dblclick` event for **each** `p` element when you creat it.

Your code can be modified like this:

```js
function pDblclick()
{
    var newContent = toAdd;
    $(this).append(newContent);
}

/* remove the old binding to all p element $('p').dblclik(...) */


/* This function is modified */
function splitLine() {
    //$("#opt").empty();
    var lines = $("textarea").val().split(/\n/g);
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        var ele;
        if ($("p:eq(" + i + ")").get(0)) {
            ele = $("p:eq(" + i + ")");
            ele.html(lines[i]);
        } else {
            ele = $("<p>");
            ele.html(lines[i]);
            ele.dblclick(pDblclick); // binding the event to the created p
            $("#opt").append($(ele).draggable());
        }
    }
}
```